Deploy Storybook to Github Pages
Trying to deploy Storybook to Github Pages, via https://dev.to/kouts/deploy-storybook-to-github-pages-3bij
but try as I might, it doesn't seem to do anything.
package.json
"build-storybook": "storybook build -s public, build-storybook -o docs-build -s ./src/static"

storybook.yml
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    paths: ["src/stories/**", "src/components/**"] # Trigger the action only when files change in the folders defined here
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - name: Install and Build 
        run: | # Install npm packages and build the Storybook files
          npm install
          npm build-storybook
      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: master # The branch the action should deploy to.
          folder: docs-build # The folder that the build-storybook script generates files.
          clean: true # Automatically remove deleted files from the deploy branch
          target-folder: docs # The folder that we serve our Storybook files from


I have updated the actions to the most recent versions, but that's not had any effect. I do see the action running on github and get a successful "pages build and deployment" message, but the /docs and the page remain empty.

add the error message
